# Getting css output using webpack ExtractTextPlugin

Tags: webpack

I am trying to get css requires to work in webpack using the ExtractTextPlugin but with no success

I want a separate css file rather than inlining any css.

Here is my webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './scripts/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/scripts/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles/styles.css', {
      allChunks: true
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'scripts')
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
    }]
  }
};
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';

require('../styles/app.css');

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, world.</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/scripts/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

styles.css is returning 404

Any idea what could be going wrong here. If I don't use the ExtractTextPlugin and just do this in config:

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
        ]
    }
```

then I get the css applied to the page correctly but obviously this is not coming from a css file

This is my first attempt at using webpack so probably doing some noob mistake

Any ideas?

Comment: I managed to get this working with font-awesome-webpack but am having issues with css as well. https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome-webpack#extract-text-webpack-plugin

Comment: Can you set up a standalone project (ie. GitHub) to study?

Comment: Can you mark an answer as accepted or describe what's not working?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`ExtractTextPlugin` needs to be added in two spots: in the Loader, and as a Plugin. Here's the example pulled from the [stylesheets documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html#separate-css-bundle).

```js
// webpack.config.js
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    // The standard entry point and output config
    entry: {
        posts: "./posts",
        post: "./post",
        about: "./about"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        chunkFilename: "[id].js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // Extract css files
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
            },
            // Optionally extract less files
            // or any other compile-to-css language
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!less-loader")
            }
            // You could also use other loaders the same way. I. e. the autoprefixer-loader
        ]
    },
    // Use the plugin to specify the resulting filename (and add needed behavior to the compiler)
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css")
    ]
}
```

Comment: In newer versions, it takes only one object as parameter: `ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback: "style-loader", use: "css-loader"})` ([docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#extract))

Comment: ***{
    context: __dirname + '/app',
    entry: {
        app: './index.js',
        vendor: ['angular', ...]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/app/bundle/js/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
              test: /\.css$/,
              loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: "style-loader", use: "css-loader" })
          }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendor', filename: 'vendor.bundle.js' }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css")
  ]};***

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your config filenames and how you include them in page

```
   var path = require('path');
   var webpack = require('webpack');
   var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './scripts/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'scripts/bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/scripts/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles/styles.css', {
      publicPath: '/styles/',
      allChunks: true
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'scripts')
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
    }]
  }
};
```

Following is the html page

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/styles/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'></div>
  </body>
  <script src="build/scripts/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to convert .svg to font file can anybody help me

Comment: @Rohitesh -> Upload svg to https://icomoon.io/app/ it will generate a font with css for icons.

Answer (score 2):

Using `css-loader` and `style-loader` together first parse your CSS, then turn it into style nodes, which can be imported in Webpack just like code. I don't understand why you'd want this artificial relationship built between your JavaScript and your CSS.

The above approach emits CSS again in the end. Why put your code through a round trip like that? Use [`raw-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) and add your main CSS file to your entry points. You lose any error-checking that `css-loader` performs, but your compilation happens much faster. But if you're using something like `sass-loader`, you'll still get all the error checking.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a webpack.config.js that works.  I don't use the same directory names you do, but I think you can see the differences and make the needed changes.  I'm also including my current module versions.

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'build/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        use: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/
      },
      {
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader'}),
        test: /\.css$/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: { limit: 40000 }
          },
          'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: 'style.css',
      allChunks: true
    })
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

// and modules:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0-rc.0"
  }
```