# Webpack: Bundle required css files

Tags: css, webpack

Being a newbie to `Webpack`, I'm following the discussion: [Recomended way to require CSS in webpack](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/176) by:

1. Configuring my Webpack configurations with

   `{
   test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/,
   loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap'],
   },`
2. Requiring css files in my code:

   `require('./style1.css');
   require('./style2.css');`

But the two css files above will not be bundled together. How to instruct `Webpack` to bundle all required `css` files?

Comment: Define "not be bundled together". If you want the CSS to be a separate file instead of included in JS, use `ExtractTextPlugin`.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi: Well, I mean all required css files must be magically combined into one big css file when being served by Webpack. Is it capable?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31462849

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi: Thank you so much! You've made my day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting css output using webpack ExtractTextPlugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730321/getting-css-output-using-webpack-extracttextplugin)

Answer (score 3):

By default webpack will not bundle your css, it will create inline style tag in HTML and place your css there. For extract all your css and bundle into one css file you nee [extract text plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin)

## for webpack 2

```
npm install --save-dev extract-text-webpack-plugin
```

## for webpack 1

```
npm install --save-dev extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1
```

**In webpack 2**

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
  ]
}
```

**Webpack 1**

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader") }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
    ]
}
```

Read more https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin

Answer (score 0):

As I saw in your Webpack configuration entires, you are instructing Webpack to bundle your css files inject then as inline css by using  `css-loader` and `style-loader`.The ***css-loader*** takes a CSS file and reads off all its dependencies whilst the ***style-loader*** will embed those styles directly into the markup as  tag in the  of the document.

Personally, just to keep things clean, I’d prefer to have a separate CSS file rather than adding all the code inline. To do that we’ll need to use a Webpack plugin called ***extract-text-webpack-plugin*** which moves every require('style.css') in entry chunks into a separate css output file. We have to install that with npm:

## for webpack 2

```
npm install --save-dev extract-text-webpack-plugin
```

## for webpack 1

```
npm install --save-dev extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1
```

Now we can update our webpack.config.js file again by requiring it and placing our CSS loader into it:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
entry: './src',
output: {
    path: 'build',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js/,
            loader: 'babel',
            include: __dirname + '/src',
        },
        {
            test: /\.css/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css")
        }
    ],
},
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
]
};
```

it then creates a styles.css file for us! We can now add this stylesheet file in the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="build/styles.css">
```